# HTMLAgilityPack InnerHTML, Wrong Parsing Error

Tags: c#, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

HTML Code

```
<p>
<Hello> World<br>
hi~
</p>
```

C# Code

```
nodes.SelectSingleNode("//p").InnerHtml
```

I want to Get

```
<Hello> World<br>
hi~
```

BUT

```
<Hello> World<br>
hi~</Hello>
```

How should I solve it?

Comment: What does "BUT" mean?

Comment: </Hello> has been added.

Comment: Looks correct to me. Why do you expect it not to automatically close the <Hello> tag?

Comment: Did you mean to write `&lt;Hello&gt;` in the HTML?

Comment: I want "<Hello> World<br>hi~" , not add </hello> closing tag

Answer (score 0):

InnterHTML returns valid HTML.

```
<Hello> World<br>
hi~
```

is not valid HTML, because the `<Hello>` gets interpreted as a HTML opening tag. Therefore, AgilityPack correctly closes that tag, to make sure you have valid HTML. 
As @Sweeper mentioned, if you want to use `<`and `>` in html, they are escapes as `&lt;` and `&gt;` to prevent them from being confused with actual html syntax. Your HTML should look like this:

```
<p>
&gt;Hello&gt; World<br>
hi~
</p>
```

See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp) for more information.